# No scrollbar in fancybox2, and set size

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've been trying to get the scrollbar to not show up in fancybox. 
I've tried out the solution at [Fancybox inline to have no scrollbars and be 100% and 'fixed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423954/fancybox-inline-to-have-no-scrollbars-and-be-100-and-fixed?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
but I can't get it to work.

The one I'm working at is http://home.nith.no/~setkin11/advancedsearc1.html
I want the size to be set to a constant and the scrollbar to not show at all when it pops up.

**Script**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#smallAdvanced_container').bind('click', function(){
            var container = $('#advanced_container');
            if($('#advanced_container').is(':hidden')) {
                $('#advanced_container').show();
                $.fancybox.open([container]);
            }
            else {
                $('#advanced_container').hide();
                $.fancybox.open([container]);    
            }
        });
        //$('#advanced_container').fancybox();
    });

    $('#advanced_container').fancybox({
         type: 'html', 
         width: 410, 
         height: 620,
         autoSize : false, 
         autoCenter: false, 
         fitToView : false,  
         scrolling : 'no' 
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="smallAdvanced_container">
    <img src="ribbon.png" alt="Search ribbon">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as though you are using the API correctly, i'm not sure you can do it without changing the plugin code.

I know a CSS way around, but it has to use !important, which is a bit of a hack. Just include the following in your CSS

```
.fancybox-inner {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you. that removed the scroll bar. Though now I get the problem of it not showing the whole content of the fancybox if the screen is smaller than it (like a tablet on its side). It gets cut

Answer (score 2):

As per Jame's answer, but if you set `overflow: auto !important` instead you will get scrollbars when you need them and not when you don't. i.e.:

```
.fancybox-inner {
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

You can also limit this to just a particular type of fancybox you might be displaying by using a specific css parent selector, e.g. to only affect a fancybox displaying iFrame content, use:

```
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-inner {
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```